# Column type setting for pgfplot were ignored

Tags: pgfplotstable

I have a `.txt` file with a table. I included in into LaTeX with `pgfplot`. Then I wanted to ignore the header of the file and added new column names etc.. It was a bit difficult because the names are a bit long. But while I was working on the table it finally worked. I got a table with my data which fits on the page and divided the words in the right way. Then I compiled it again...and since that my `column type` setting are completely ignored and the table is too big for the page. Though I changed nothing. That's what it looks like this:

[image]

I have no idea what went wrong from one second to the other. I already tried restarting, another version of compiling, etc.. I'm really confused. Does anyone have an idea?
Here is my code:

```
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.8}


\begin{table}[h!]
\caption{In dieser Tabelle sind die Beugungsordnungen, die Lage der Minima in px dargestellt. Weiterhin sind die nach obigen Formeln die berechneten Werte für den Betrag des Abstandes zwischen den Minima und dem Hauptmaximum in px, der gleiche Abstand in m und der Beugungswinkel $\Theta$ und die dazugehörigen Sinus-Werte eingetragen.}
\begin{center}
%%% Code from Dr. Christian ------ for not using headers.----------------------
\pgfkeysifdefined{/pgfplots/table/output empty row/.@cmd}{
    % upcoming releases offer this more convenient option:
    \pgfplotstableset{
        empty header/.style={
          every head row/.style={output empty row},
        }
    }
}{
    % versions up to and including 1.5.1 need this:
    \pgfplotstableset{
        empty header/.style={
            typeset cell/.append code={%
                \ifnum\pgfplotstablerow=-1 %
                    \pgfkeyssetvalue{/pgfplots/table/@cell content}{}%
                \fi
            }
        }
    }
}
\pgfplotstabletypeset[col sep=space,empty header,  
%begin table=\bgroup\small\setlength{\tabcolsep}{3pt}\begin{longtable},
%end table=\end{longtable}\egroup,
    col sep=space,
    columns/0/.style={column type={p{1cm}}},
    columns/1/.style={ column type={p{1,8cm}}},
    columns/2/.style={column type={p{2,7cm}}},
    columns/3/.style={column type={p{2,5cm}}},
    columns/4/.style={column type={p{1,6cm}}},
    columns/5/.style={column type={p{1,5cm}}},
%column type=l,
every head row/.append style={before row={%
    \toprule
   n Mininum & Lage der Min. in $px$ & Betrag Abstand Min.  zum Hauptmax. in $px$ & Betrag Abstand $x_{n}$ zum Hauptmax. in $m$ & Beugungs- winkel $\Theta$ in $rad$ &sin$\Theta_{n}$\\\toprule
        },
        after row=\midrule,
    },
every last row/.style={
        after row=\bottomrule}
]{CalcPlot/tabledata2.txt}

\end{center}
\end{table}
```

Comment: why not updating the package to 1.14 to start with? So you can delete Christian's temporary fix.

Comment: also I think you need `display columns` if you want to use column indices

Comment: @percusse thank you so much. Now it works! But it's still crazy, that I really worked with my code a few times...